# Correlate item in dataframe based on character string in r

Tags: r, string, correlation

I currently have the dataset newdat, a dataframe containing item scores:

```
set.seed(1)
newdat <- setNames(data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:5,10,replace=TRUE))),paste0("i",1:5))

   i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
1   2  2  5  3  5
2   2  1  2  3  4
3   3  4  4  3  4
4   5  2  1  1  3
5   2  4  2  5  3
6   5  3  2  4  4
7   5  4  1  4  1
8   4  5  2  1  3
9   4  2  5  4  4
10  1  4  2  3  4
```

I also have the character strings "newCV" and "newDV" which are:

```
newCV <- c("i3","i2")
newDV <- c("i1")
```

I am attempting to correlate DV with all of the items except itself, and the items contained in newCV. I have tried the following:

```
corr<-cor(newdat,use="complete.obs")[-which(colnames(newdat)==c(newCV,newDV)),which(colnames(newdat)==c(newCV,newDV))]
```

Which works if there is nothing found in CV, but if there is something in CV I get an error and no results.  Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: `cor(newdat[newDV], newdat[!(names(newdat) %in% c(newCV, newDV))],
    use="complete.obs")`

Comment: @user20650 yes that looks good, submit as an answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to calculate the specific correlations you can select what columns to pass to `cor`

```
cor(newdat[newDV], newdat[!(names(newdat) %in% c(newCV, newDV))], 
                                                      use="complete.obs")
```